# Best way to model this mushroom

Tags: modeling, displacement

I have already modeled the mushroom but i'm not sure how best to approach the grooves at the top of the mushroom.[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess displacement would be the best option here, did you unwrap the object?

Comment: Not yet. Figured i would finish the modelling first. I have tried displacement didn't like the results.

Comment: If it's for a game, a texture would be necessary as making the mushroom would require too many faces, slightly laggy. Personally, i'd use textures even if it isn't a game.

Comment: When modeling is done you rather need materials than more details, in this case an x-scaled muscrave texture as bump mixed with a translucent material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably just sculpt that detail in sculpt mode with dyntopo enabled and detail size set to 3 - 5. I'd probably make the hat of the mushroom a separate object in order not to mess up the nice topology of the rest of the model. Also, if you keep a copy of the hat as it is now, you could then later use the high-res sculpted hat to bake displacement and/or normal maps to the low-res hat, if you're concerned about performance or render times for your final scene.